# Boost path inclusions dilemma with Mingw

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin, mingw, boost-thread

I have an issue with Mingw and boost. I use a cygwin environment

```cpp
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <cmath>
int main(){ return 0; }
```

If I compile with this command I get the following error

`i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.o`

`test.cpp:1:28: fatal error: boost/thread.hpp: No such file or directory`

And if I include `/usr/include` to get boost/thread.hpp, the wrong cmath header seem to be included:

`i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include test.cpp -o test.o`

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/random:38:0,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:67,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/algorithm:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:42,
             from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
             from /usr/include/boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp:17,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:9,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
             from test.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/cmath:1046:11: error: '::acoshl' has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/cmath:1050:11: error: '::asinhl' has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/cmath:1054:11: error: '::atanhl' has not been declared
....
```

What can I do here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mingw and cygwin are two different platforms. Cygwin is a POSIX-conform platform and supports many commands that can also be found on most UNIX platforms. mingw, on the other hand, is a target-platform to compile "pure" windows applications, usually used as a cross-compiler from a posix environment (like in your case: cygwin) to generate Windows binaries. Trying to use cygwin's version of boost while creating a mingw binary is similar to using the linux version of boost when compiling for Mac OS X. You wouldn't expect that to work either.

To install a mingw version of boost simply download and unpack boost. Invoke the following in the boost source directory:

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

Now edit the file `project-config.jam` and change the line starting with `using gcc` to:

```
using gcc : : i686-pc-mingw32-g++ ;
```

then invoke:

```
./bjam --prefix=/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/usr --layout=system variant=release threading=multi link=shared runtime-link=shared toolset=gcc target-os=windows threadapi=win32 stage
./bjam --prefix=/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/usr --layout=system variant=release threading=multi link=shared runtime-link=shared toolset=gcc target-os=windows threadapi=win32 install
```

The prefix `/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/usr` may be wrong on your setup, so check that it exists. Also change the values of `threading=multi link=shared runtime-link=shared` to your needs.

You can also find useful comments at [Boost - cross compile - "from Linux" "to Windows"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399252/boost-cross-compile-from-linux-to-windows)

Also, do **not** forget to remove `-I/usr/include` as this will make gcc just use cygwin's version of boost again.